# How to create custom array adapter when items defined dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, view, imagebutton

I have a custom adapter which is supposed to contain image buttons. However, I am bit confused on the implementation of the override for the getView() method. Since my image buttons are defined dynamically, I am able to recover an image button by using the code

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup){
    ImageButton ibutton = (ImageButton) getItem(i);
```

How do I return its view? I have not specifically created an xml file for it since it is just an ImageButton (not in combination with anything else), but is it necessary to create an xml for it? Or is there a way to easily get the view from the imagebutton itself.

When I try this for getView(), the imagebutton is not clickable for some reason.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageButton imageButton = getItem(position);
    return imageButton ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to build you adapter something like this:

```
public class ImageButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private Context mContext;

   // Constructor
   public ImageButtonAdapter(Context c) {
      mContext = c;
   }

   public int getCount() {
      return listCount;
   }

   public Object getItem(int position) {
      return null;
   }

   public long getItemId(int position) {
      return 0;
   }

   // create a new ImageButton for each item referenced by the Adapter
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ImageButton imageButton ;

      if (convertView == null) {
         imageButton = new ImageButton (mContext);
         imageButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
      } 
      else 
      {
         imageButton = (ImageButton ) convertView;
      }
      imageButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
      return imageButton ;
   } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I didn't know that ImageButton itself can be returned as a view.

Comment: Sorry, actually, when I tried to use the getView method, the imagebuttons didn't show up for some reason. Would you know why? (I commented out the layout params line for now) I updated the original question also with another issue that the imagebutton can't be clicked.

Comment: Did you try setting a clickListener on the image button something like this:   imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("position","position"+position);
            }
        });